# How to replace a pandas column row with the previous row if a condition is met

Tags: python, back-testing

I'm trying to speed up my trading strategy backtesting.

Right now, I have

```
for i in trange(1, len(real_choice), disable=not backtesting, desc="Converting HOLDs and calculating backtest correct/incorrect... [3/3]"):
      if (advice[i] == "HOLD"):
        advice[i] = advice[i-1]
      if (real_choice[i] == "HOLD"):
        real_choice[i] = real_choice[i-1]

      if advice[i] == real_choice[i]:
        correct[i] = "CORRECT"
      else:
        correct[i] =  "INCORRECT"
```

This part of the code takes the longest, so I want to speed it up.

I'm learning Python so this was simple and worked but now I'm paying for it with how long the backtests take.

Is there a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.where` to compare two columns and assign a value to those rows

```
correct = np.where( advice == real_choice
                     , "CORRECT", "INCORRECT)
```

but to make it look more pandas it would be

```
df['correct'] = np.where( df['advice'] == df['real_choice']
                     , "CORRECT", "INCORRECT)
```

with some time comparisons
(Full Code)

```
A = randint(0, 10, 10000)

B = randint(0, 10, 10000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B':B, 'C': "INCORRECT"})
print(df)


start = time.process_time()
for i in range(0, len(real_choice)):
      if df['A'][i] == df['B'][i]:
        df['C'][i] = "CORRECT"
      else:
        df['C'][i] =  "INCORRECT"
print("method 1", time.process_time() - start)


start = time.process_time()
df['C2'] = np.where( df['A'] == df['B'], "CORRECT", "INCORRECT")
print("method 2", time.process_time() - start)
```

method 2 took a shorter amount of time to compute

```
method 1 1.0530679999999997
method 2 0.0022619999999999862
```

Comment: Seems to be slower, unfortunately. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, I think so, i did some time comparisons, please see edit

Comment: I see now, I actually did have it working before but now I'm having issues because the rest of the code then calculates a percent correct, and that code does not work with the data type that `np.where` converts it to. Any idea how to fix that, or should I make another question?

Comment: Hmmm, I think that might be good for another question but i might be able to help, what was the datatype before vs the one it is now?

Comment: It was just a pandas dataframe column that I created by doing `correct = df['correct']`. Type() returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` if that's any help. The code I use after that is `num_incorrect = correct.str.count("INCORRECT").sum() `, and that no longer works with the faster numpy way.